# Cherrypy 3.2 sessions broken, or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: cherrypy

Running python 3 with cherrypy 3.2, and have been having a host of problems. First of all, to get cookies to work, i had to fake a fqdn in /etc/hosts.

```
e.g. 
http://test:8080 [no cookies]
http://test.local:8080 [cookies work]
```

After this, I tried to get sessions to work, but I am getting a new session id each time, and no session_id value is being set in a cookie anywhere in the browser.

```
class HelloWorld:
  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self, *args):

    print("\n\n")
    ###   test cookies (works fine, no problems)
    print(cherrypy.request.cookie)
    cherrypy.response.cookie['c1'] = 'val1'
    cherrypy.response.cookie['c1']['max-age'] = '3600'   

    cherrypy.response.cookie['d1'] = 'val2'
    cherrypy.response.cookie['d1']['max-age'] = '3600'   

    ###   test sessions (doesn't work)

    print(cherrypy.session.load()) # always returns None

    print(cherrypy.session.id) # different every refresh

    print(cherrypy.session.get('foo')) # always returns None
    cherrypy.session['foo'] = 'bar'

    cherrypy.session.save() # apparently has no effect

  return "Hello world!"
```

Can anyone offer some advice or suggestions? I see that no no cookie with the session id is being set in chrome, even though my other values are.

My config looks like:

```
'/': {'tools.sessions.on': True,
      'tools.sessions.timeout': 7200}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the 'answer' button isn't clickable now. I figured this out through trial and error, hopefully this helps someone else. The solution was to specify any value for tools.sessions.name, e.g. {'tools.sessions.name': 'hhh'} in the config. Not sure why this isn't in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. I added `tools.sessions.name` to the cherrypy config and now it works